# How to call ps1 script from Jenkins with multiple parameters

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

Why does this work :

`powershell returnStatus: true, script: ".\\runCCMGeneric.ps1"`

but this doesn't

`powershell returnStatus: true, script: ".\\runCCMGeneric.ps1 HMLTCCM HMLSJARI load SystemTest multiple HMLTCCM getPatches"`

What syntax should I be using to call a PoSh script with multiple parameters from a Jenkins pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

within the pipeline, you have to use tripple quotes to make the arguments work.

```
powershell returnStatus: true, script: """
       .\\runCCMGeneric.ps1 HMLTCCM HMLSJARI load SystemTest multiple HMLTCCM getPatches
"""
```

if arguments are values from pipeline parameters, you will need to use `$env:HMLTCCM` etc.

Comment: Thanks Jawad, that's got me sorted